# Accessing Parent global variable in iFrame url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have following code Placed in my domain as `thedomain.com/myapp/index.php`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ERROR);

$storeId = 123;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<iframe src="thedomain.com/myapp/thurber/index.php" width="850" target="_parent" height="850" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; border:none;" ></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In my thurber/index.php  i want to access the parent variable `$storeId`

Is this possible? if so How can i achieve it?

Comment: You can create includes/constant_variables.php, store all constant variables in there that are shared and include it in every file you need, just don't expect any changes to this value will affect anything except the current file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the variable via $_GET:

```
<iframe src="thedomain.com/myapp/thurber/index.php?sid=<?php echo $storeId; ?>" width="850" target="_parent" height="850" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; border:none;" ></iframe>
```

In thurber/index.php you can access it via `$_GET['sid']`. Note that this can be manipulated and you pass only the value which is set when the echo is executed. If you change the value later, thurber/index.php still works with the old value.

**EDIT (for multiple):**

```
<iframe src="thedomain.com/myapp/thurber/index.php?sid=<?php echo $storeId; ?>&var_two=<?php echo $var_two; ?>" width="850" target="_parent" height="850" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; border:none;" ></iframe>
```

Access via `$_GET['var_two']`

Comment: problem is i have two more variables. So is there any better alternative than that?

Comment: You can use multiple @MuhammadUmar just seperate them by `&`

Answer (score 0):

Sharing php variables trough an iframe is inpossible. However, using `cURL` you can pass variables and fetch the output from the other file to print it on your page.